# Stop background music for cocos2d Android

Tags: java, android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

To stop the background Music after pressing "PlayGame" button in cocos2d-android, have given like `SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.rock, true);` since i could not find code for stop background music, i have given pause method, once i resume the game again the music starts, but i need to abort the music after splashscreen itself, I have search but could not find for cocos2d-android game engine, please do help me.

Answer (score 0):

On the press of Play Button use below line  :

```
SoundEngine.sharedEngine().pauseSound();
```

Comment: i had used pauseSound();, but this did not workout perfectly, if game restarts again Background Music gets started, but i should not get like this @AM

Comment: where are you calling the background sound ?

Comment: In splashScreen as SoundEngine.sharedEngine().playSound(context, R.raw.rock, true);, i need sound only for splash and not for the next layer @AM

Comment: you are using the splash Screen in Activity or Using some trick  in CCLayer look like splash screen ?

Comment: if you have onExit() method where you are using the splash screen . put above line of code into the onExit() method